# Which is the best place to search for a filed/issued patent?

Tags: search, patent-search, databases, google-patents, wipo

Which is the de facto and most recognizable patent DB in the world? Is it [WIPO's database](https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/search.jsf) (the search engine and the interface seem limited) or [Google Patents](https://patents.google.com/) or maybe anything else? What is the difference between these and do they cover every country in Europe and also the States?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I find problems with Google Patents not finding all the relevant patents when I search. It is, however handy for finding an individual patent quickly. I prefer [The Lens](https://www.lens.org/lens/) which I find more full featured, especially if you register (free). Ultimately, if you want detailed file histories, there is no substitute for individual country databases like the [US Public Pair](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) for the the US. I find [Espacenet](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/?locale=en_EP) useful for European patents.

Comment: What about WIPO?

Comment: I've not used WIPO much. It looks good if a bit barebones from the UI standpoint. The professional patent librarians I've worked for generally used paid databases like TotalPatent or Micropatent. Hopefully, you'll get another answer which expands on mine.